# Dataflow jobs hanging - no warnings or errors given

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We've got a Dataflow pipeline that reads from BigQuery. It's trying to read ~10M records. Everything looks healthy - no errors or no warnings. But the job just hangs when trying to read from BigQuery. We left it for 15 mins, but still 0 records read. In the end we had to cancel the job.

Some example job ID's

- 2015-06-24_17_55_06-15252989544958442335
- 2015-06-24_18_11_43-5648996119225591199

Is there something wrong with the service currently?

Comment: IIRC a few months ago when I tried to read from BigQuery it showed no progress until all of the data was read, so maybe it's worth to wait a bit longer. 10M records sounds like quite a lot of data.

Comment: We've got other pipelines reading billions of rows from BQ, and they show reading the records within a few minutes. 10M isn't really a lot for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a permission problem reading from a BigQuery table. However, the errors were not visible in the job. When we enabled cloud logging, then the job failed and the errors showed up. The Google engineers are looking into why the job hangs when cloud logging is not enabled, and when an error occurs.